# Add a no to each element of a list in prolog

Tags: prolog

i am new to Prolog. I am suppose to write Create a ternary predicate which will add the
first parameter, a number, to each number in the second parameter, a list.  The third parameter will hold the result.

e.g.

```
?-addparam1(4,[a,3,6,b,8],X).
X=[a,7,10,b,12]
```

I wrote the following code:

```
test(X , [] ,[] ).
test(X , [H|T] ,[A|B]) :- add(X,H,A),test(X,T,B).

add(X,H,K):-K  is H +X.
```

It works fine if I give only numbers in the list but not for alphabets. I tried using an if statement

```
add(X,H,K):- atom(H)->K  is H ; K  is H +X.
```

but still it didn't give the result.

Comment: formatting really heightens the chance of getting responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost right. `is` is the wrong operator, you'll want `=`. Also, it might be saver to check with `number/1`. Since `[a]` and `a(b)` also aren't atoms, but aren't numbers either.

This way it becomes:

```
add(X,H,K):- 
  number(H)->
  K is H+X;
  K = H.
```